# Meaning of 私が、安心します

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the passage below, I am a bit unsure how to understand the bolded part. Part of my confusion is thinking how the utterance is meant to be interpreted. Is she saying she is relived after hearing what her friend told her?, Is she saying holding the cat makes her relived? Or something else.

> 「抱き方、教えてあげますよ」
>
> 「ネコは猫背なので、体を丸めるように」
>
> 「こうでしょうか」
>
> 「そそ。じょーずです。で、肘に座らせる感じで」
>
> 「あとは、軽く手を添えて」
>
> 「（抱き）よしよし」
>
> 「先輩の場合、おっぱいすごいから」
>
> 「やはり、お邪魔でしょうか」
>
> 「いや、逆に安心するんじゃないかなって」
>
> 「んっ…**私が、安心します**」

Comment: Reading the passage, I think it is not sufficient to guess what the bold part is meant. More context is needed. I would like to know the conversation after this.

Comment: Would you mind telling me where you found this dialogue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "It's (not the cat but) me who will be relieved" or "*I* will be relieved". Note that she explicitly said 私, followed by an **exhaustive-listing が**, which signals there's a contrast between 私 and the cat. If the sempai simply wanted to say "I'm relieved (after hearing what you told me)", this exhaustive-listing 私が would not be necessary.

> A: 先輩の場合、おっぱいすごいから
> Because you (=Sempai) have amazing boobs...
>
> B: やはり、お邪魔でしょうか
> Are these (=my breasts) annoying (to the cat)?
>
> A: いや、逆に安心するんじゃないかなって
> No, I thought they would make the cat relieved.
>
> B: んっ…**私が**、安心します
> Hmm...It's (not the cat but) *me* who will be relieved (by holding the cat).